# Windows Mobile 5 Smartphone DNS error for local html files

Tags: windows-mobile, compact-framework, mobile, webbrowser-control, gprs

Im getting a DNS timeout error in Windows mobile five when ever I try to load a local html file into WebBrowser view control after viewing an online page.

eg ctrlBrowser.Url = new Url("http://www.google.com"); followed by ctrlBrowser.Url = new Url("file:///\My Documents\test.html");

However it I try to open local file only with gprs closed and no previous requests to external pages it works fine. This is not an issue on WM 6 and 5, the only place I get this issue is on WM 5 smartphone physical device.

Im baffeled here as how to solve.

Your thoughts are much appreciated.

Tony

Answer (score 0):

This seems unrelated, but I'll share it in case I'm wrong: Firefox [disables file: URLs in network served (http: and https:) pages](http://www-archive.mozilla.org/quality/networking/testing/filetests.html).  Maybe the WebBrowser control just doesn't like showing file: URLs after network pages.